# ColdFusion ORMExecuteQuery ORM missing mapping

Tags: orm, coldfusion, hql, cfml, coldfusion-2018

I am trying to use `ORMExecuteQuery`. To do queries something like this:

```
ORMExecuteQuery("select count(*) from Customer");
```

This shows an error. So I have reduced the complexity of statement now to something smaller

```
// This works
rc.Customers = EntityLoad("Customer");

// This crashes
rc.Customers2 = ORMExecuteQuery("from Customer");
```

[image]

Comment: I have seen issues with ORMExecuteQuery() and the case of the object name. Have you tried ORMExecuteQuery("from customer"); ?

Comment: That worked. You should write it up as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen issues with ORMExecuteQuery() and the case of the object name.

Try using

```
ORMExecuteQuery("from customer");
```